# Python list wildcard match with another list

Tags: python, list, match, wildcard

Let's say I have two Python lists (one 2D, one 1D):

```
array1 = [['cat', 'dog', 'house', 'mouse'], ['life', 'meaning', 'deep', 'ocean'], ['long', 'happy']]
array2 = ['life', 'meaning']
```

Now I would like to find a matching result in `array1` by using `array2` as my wildcard. I will define it as a rough idea in code (this is not the actual code, it's just a thought of what I want):

```
for i in range(len(array1)):
   if array1[i] == array2 + *:
      print(array1[i])
```

In such case, the program would return this `array1` element `[life, meaning, deep, ocean]` because it matches wildcard from `array2` `[life, meaning] + anything` .

**Is it possible to do such wildcard list match in Python?** I've came across function `fnmatch.filter(names, pattern)`, although I'm not sure if it can take whole array as a pattern. In worst case scenario I could just loop through the arrays and do simple `if` check on each element, but I don't think that would be very efficient.

Thank you.

Comment: Better to use `'###'.join(array2) in '###'.join(array1_items)` for items in array1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you are working with strings.

```py
array1 = [["cat", "dog", "house", "mouse"], ["life", "meaning", "deep", "ocean"], ["long", "happy"]]
array2 = ["life", "meaning"]

[all(x in y for x in array2) for y in array1]
# returns [False, True, False]
```

You can then proceed to get the index of any `True` elements in the boolean array and continue with that.